# SP.ClientContext in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sp.js

I want to use:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

I get the error:

> SCRIPT 445: Object doesn't support this action.

I found out that

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateProjectEC, "sp.js");
```

or

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', updateProjectEC);
```

could solve the problem, but it didn't solve the problem in my case.

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 and I get the feeling that Sharepoint 2013 is necessary to use the `ClientContext()` function. Is that really the case?

And if it's the case, is there a similar function with the same purpose?

Comment: Hi,
Check whether SP.JS is getting loaded or not ? if not then try loading like below:
SP.SOD.RegisterSod("SP.js", "\_layouts\SP.js");

Comment: Can you share your full code ? Also, can you tell where you are calling this script from ?(Inside a Content editor ? )

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

and

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateProjectEC, "sp.js");
```